# ExpandableListView with custom row backgrounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

[image]

[image]

I'm an Android newbie. I want to create a screen with some expandable headers as illustrated. I've created the 1st row "gff" as shown. 
However, each row under gff shows a space in between rows. Also, the ListView does'nt fill the width of the screen and leaves a margin on the sides and above.

How can I get the header and caption to fill the entire length of the screen as shown in the diagram? Also, how can I get the rows to show a different color?

Is there an example or code that does something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting divider of ListView to null, like `listView.setDivider(null)`, this should help. Also you can set `listView.setSelector(null)` this should remove unnecessary margins.

Comment: Great, this works. How about the space at the margins? Is it possible to set different colors for each row?

Comment: Gives me a null exception. I've adjusted this by removing all padding for the <Relativelayout tag in the layout file. Do you know how to set different colors for each row?

Comment: you have to implement `getChildView` in your `ExpandableListAdapter`, this would allow you to supply different views and colors for child views.

Comment: All right. Thanks a lot for your help. Really enjoyed our coding session. Cheers!